# Explanation of Yesod route parsing

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm building a library for Yesod which, I hope, will expose an interface for Stripe, the credit card processor.  (I plan on releasing it soon.  I gave up on Amazon because of its poorly documented API...)

I have created a subsite and typeclass to handle the routes the Stripe API needs.  I managed to figure out the "how" of what I need to do, but I don't quite understand it.

The subsite has routes defined by:

```
mkYesodSubData "Stripe" [parseRoutes|
  /charge/#StripeId     ChargeR   POST
  /customer/#StripeId   CustomerR POST
|]
```

and the parent has the route defined as:

```
/payment/stripe   StripeR Stripe appStripe
```

Now, I'm curious about what this line actually means.  For comparison, most other routes are defined like:

```
/questions       QuestionsR GET
```

As far as I understand, the route generator generates a `QuestionsR` data type, and dispatches `/questions` to `getQuestionsR`.  But what exactly is the route generator doing with

```
/payment/stripe   StripeR Stripe appStripe
```

I suppose it must be creating a `StripeR` type.  And I know that `appStripe :: App -> Stripe`.  But what roles do these things play?  How does the parser know to ensure that `StripeR` takes one of the `Stripe` routes as an argument?  What's going on behind the scenes, and is the `GET` case a special case of the other pattern?

Comment: Check this: [Yesod and subsites: a no-brainer](http://monoid.se/haskell/yesod-and-subsites/); and this: [Yesod Book - Creating a Subsite](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/creating-a-subsite); and this for deeper sight: [Yesod book basics - routing](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics)

Comment: Your first link seems to route to spam now, just FYI @GabrielRiba

Comment: @Neikos I am sorry for the link but there was interesting stuff there. Probably the web publisher did not renew the Internet domain name. Here is the old stuff: http://archive.is/20130418103559/monoid.se/haskell/yesod-and-subsites/

Answer (score 2):

The GET isn't really a special case as I understand it, as we are explicitly creating a Resource that is a subsite.

The line in question

`/payment/stripe StripeR Stripe appStripe`

Says that the resource at /payment/stripe we are going to call `StripeR` and it's a `Stripe` (which is a subsite) that can be accessed with the `appStripe` function.

For example, when you are defining your foundation for the subsite you do something like

```
data Stripe = Stripe
```

But you could also do

```
data Stripe = Stripe {
  getStripeConfig :: String
}
```

then in the Master site you co uld do in a handler

```
handler :: Handler Html
handler = do
  app <- getYesod
  let stripeConfig = getStripeConfig $ appStripe app
  ...
```